# vbCode is autocomplete is not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am new to VB.net I want get list of names from my DB with auto complete. I am trying to follow the following [example](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/05/ajax-autocompleteextender-sample.html).

But My problem is it not working and I was not getting any error can any one tell me where I am doing wrong.

My home.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="VB"  CodeFile="~/home.aspx.vb" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="_home"%>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScripManager1" runat="server"/>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="autoupdate" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>


    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                          <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender2" runat="server" 
                  TargetControlID="txtSearch" ServiceMethod="GetList" MinimumPrefixLength="3"
                  UseContextKey="True" >
          </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>



</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my home.aspx.vb

```
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Web.Services

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function GetCompletionList(ByVal prefixText As String, ByVal count As Integer, ByVal contextKey As String) As String()
        Try

            Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Test").ConnectionString)
            con.Open()
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select LoginName from users where LoginName like '@Name' +'%' ", con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", prefixText)
            'Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            'Dim dt As New DataTable()
            'da.Fill(dt)
            'Dim InviteSearchListresult As New List(Of String)()
            'For i As Integer = 1 To dt.Rows.Count
            '    InviteSearchListresult.Add(dt.Rows(i)(1).ToString())
            '    Next
            Dim result As New List(Of String)()
            Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            While dr.Read()
                result.Add(dr("LoginName").ToString())
            End While

            Return (
        From m In result
        Where m.StartsWith(prefixText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
        Select m).Take(count).ToArray()
        Catch ex As Exception


        End Try
 End Function
End Class
```

Please help how to solve this issuse.

Comment: You have an empty try-catch in the Pokemon pattern there, are you putting a breakpoint on that to see if there is an issue during debug (I hope) or is that something you want to leave in your code (please don't)?

Answer (score 0):

Your service method is **GetList** but your actual method name is **GetCompletionList**.

Try getting the method names to match up and see if that's the problem. You're trying to call a method that doesn't exist.

Comment: Did it work? Can you set a breakpoint in your web method and actually hit the breakpoint? If not, your method still isn't being called.

Comment: Are you getting any results when you step through the method? It sounds like your array isn't getting generated.